# Scrapy Follow scraped links to get more Data

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I want to follow the links that I've scraped to get more details.

For example, from [here](https://singapore.craigslist.com.sg/d/jobs/search/jjj), which contains all the job titles.

I wish to go to one of the links, for example, [here](https://singapore.craigslist.com.sg/sls/d/1-million-qualified-leads-for/6546311563.html) to extract the job descriptions.

Below is my working code for getting the Title Link and Date as well as getting them to insert into a CSV File.

```
    class MySpider(BaseSpider):
        name = "craigslist"
        allowed_domains = ["singapore.craigslist.com.sg"]
        start_urls = ["https://singapore.craigslist.com.sg/d/jobs/search/jjj"]

    def parse(self, response):
       item = SampleItem()
       item["title"] = response.xpath('//*[@class="result-info"]/a/text()').extract()
       item["link"] = response.xpath('//*[@class="result-info"]/a/@href').extract()
       item["date"] = response.xpath('//*[@class="result-info"]/time[@class="result-date"]/text()').extract()
       for i in range(len(item["title"])):
           yield {"Title": item['title'][i], "Link": item['link'][i], "Date": item['date'][i]}
```

This is my attempt to go to the link but it hasn't been successful.

```
    class MySpider(BaseSpider):
        name = "craigslist"
        allowed_domains = ["singapore.craigslist.com.sg"]
        start_urls = ["https://singapore.craigslist.com.sg/d/jobs/search/jjj"]

        BASE_URL = 'https://singapore.craigslist.com.sg'

       def parse(self, response):
          links = response.xpath('//*[@class="result-info"]/a/@href').extract()

          item = SampleItem()
          item["title"] = response.xpath('//*[@class="result-info"]/a/text()').extract()
          item["date"] = response.xpath('//*[@class="result-info"]/time[@class="result-date"]/text()').extract()
          for i in range(len(item["title"])):
             yield {"Title": item['title'][i], "Date": item['date'][i]}

          for link in links:
             absolute_url = self.BASE_URL + link
             yield BaseSpider.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_attr)

        def parse_attr(self, response):
           item = SampleItem()
           item["description"] = response.xpath('//*[@id="postingbody"]/text()').extract()
           for i in range(len(item["description"])):
               yield {"Description" : item["description"]}
```

Any idea how to do this?
[Log of scraper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z231L.png)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken your links object contains the whole links to the next page... Why the need to add a self.BASE_URL ? Doesn't just yielding a request with 'url=link' instead of url='absolute_url' work ?. Also any log or error description that could help us figure out the problem ?

Comment: There isn't any error because it did not go into the link to scrape the job description 

I am not too sure of the codes, i got them from some other people asking similar questions

Comment: Can you then provide the log of the scraper running ?

Comment: added the log of scraper

Comment: Well it says pretty obviously that 'Object BaseSpider has no attribute Request', try replacing 'BaseSpider.Request' with the scrapy Request . By the way you seem to have no clue what your code actually does and I suggest you use the scrapy [documentation] (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/) to try to understand how your scraper works